# Python-compare and sort two lists of numbers and return them in ascending order

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = [1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4 ,4, 4, 5,5,5,5]
list_2 = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
```

I want to return the list of elements that appear only in the first list but not in the second and the list should be sorted ascending so the result is like this:

```
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

So far I have this:

```
def sorted_nums(list_1,list2_2):
    c = (set(list_1) - set(list_2))
    d = dict.fromkeys(c, 0)
    for index in list_1:
        if index in c:
            d[index]+=1
    return d
a = sorted_nums(list_1,list_2)
b = sorted(a.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])
print(b)
```

and it returns this:

```
[(1,2), (3,2), (2,3), (4,5)]
```

Could you help me to change the last part of the code so that I get the result I want?

Comment: How is `[1, 3, 2, 4]` in ascending order? Do you mean `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: Edit your question by stating sort in terms of occurrence.

Comment: None of the elements in the first list appears in the second list and the list is already in ascending order. Can you clarify the question and the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a `map`

```py
def sorted_nums(list_1,list2_2):
    c = (set(list_1) - set(list_2))
    d = dict.fromkeys(c, 0)
    for index in list_1:
        if index in c:
            d[index]+=1
    return d

list_1 = [1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4 ,4, 4, 5,5,5,5] 
list_2 = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
a = sorted_nums(list_1,list_2)
b = list(map(lambda x:x[0],sorted(a.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]))) ## changed here
print(b)
```

```py
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Apply function `lambda x:x[0]` over each and every elements using `map`

Answer (score 2):

You just want to sort by the occurance (counts) of lis1, taking the set-difference from the second list:

```
>>> list1 = [1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4 ,4, 4, 5,5,5,5]
>>> list2 = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts1 = Counter(list1)
>>> sorted(counts1.keys() - set(list2), key=counts1.get)
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1:

By using `sorted(array, key = list_1.count)` to sort by occurrence but this will be slow.

```
list_1 =  [1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4 ,4, 4, 5,5,5,5]
list_2 = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]

def sorted_nums(list_1,list2_2):
    return sorted(list(set(list_1) - set(list_2)), key = list_1.count)

sorted_nums(list_1, list_2)
```

### Method 2 [(Credits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429426/sorting-a-list-by-frequency-of-occurrence-in-a-list):

By using `Counter`. This is a faster approach. :

```
from collections import Counter

list_1 =  [1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4 ,4, 4, 5,5,5,5]
list_2 = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
counter_1 = Counter(list1)
def sorted_nums(list_1,list2_2):
    return sorted(counter_1.keys() - set(list2), key=counter_1.get)

sorted_nums(list_1, list_2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `set` operations

```
a =  [1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4 ,4, 4, 5,5,5,5]
b =  [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]

c = sorted(list(set(a) - set(b)))
print(c)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result I need is [1, 3, 2, 4]. So out of those two lists I have I need to create a third one and this will be sorted by the number of occurrence in the first

Answer (score 0):

You already have it sorted. So you need to extract the first element?

```
print([x[0] for x in b])
```

Comment: The line is to be added just after all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with the default order for tied counts, this is quite succinct:

```py
from collections import Counter

list_1 = [1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4 ,4, 4, 5,5,5,5]
list_2 = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]

blacklist = set(list_2)

c = Counter(i for i in list_1 if i not in blacklist)

[n for n,_ in reversed(c.most_common())]
```

The output is `[3, 1, 2, 4]` (note the counts for 1 and 3 are the same).

If you can rely on the ordering of your list_1 to be as it is in your example (all clusters are consecutive) you can do a bit better using `itertools.groupby`:

```py
import itertools.groupby

c = sorted((len(list(g)), i) for i, g in itertools.groupby(list_1) if i not in blacklist)

[i for _, i in c]
```

Output is `[1, 3, 2, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the question leads me to this:

```
list_1 = [1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4 ,4, 4, 5,5,5,5]
list_2 = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]

d = dict()
list_2_s = set(list_2)
for e in list_1:
    if e not in list_2_s:
        d[e] = d.setdefault(e, 0) + 1
lst = [t[1] for t in sorted((v, k) for k, v in d.items())]
print(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

`list(dict.fromkeys(list_1))` this is working same as `set` but keep order of elements

```
def sorted_nums(list_1,list_2):
return tuple(filter(lambda x: x not in set(list_2), list(dict.fromkeys(list_1))))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).